# Create a new column in pandas matching the string to another string

Tags: python, pandas, string, nlp

I have a dataframe, where I have a string that contains the web content for a website.

```
    _id                             webContent
0   6023f430e341d28c23358b1f    ponderosa mushrooms specialty foods squarespac...
1   6023f432e341d28c23358b36    var __ccenabled false context graph meet lates...
2   6023f432e341d28c23358b42    orchards ocean crisp apple company wsite eleme...
3   6023f433e341d28c23358b79    stutz cider wsite elements wsite footer div pa...
4   6023f434e341d28c23358bcd    story beere brewing company try typekit load c...
```

I have another dataframe, which contains, keywords.

[image]

```
Keywords    Category
0   Support Agricultural inputs
1   Soil preparation    Agricultural inputs
2   Préparation du sol  Agricultural inputs
3   Planting    Agricultural inputs
4   Planter Agricultural inputs
... ... ...
195 Chambre Consumption/Services
196 Dormitories Consumption/Services
197 Dortoirs    Consumption/Services
198 Workers' Camps  Consumption/Services
199 Camps de travailleurs   Consumption/Services
```

Now, I want to create new column in dataframe 1 named Category , which tells if any of the words in string in web content of dataframe 1 matches with the keywords of dataframe 2 for each row.

I also did this on df2, but I am not sure, if its helpful.
[image]

Please let me know if my point is not clear enought.

Comment: What if you match multiple?

Comment: I added the code for the second DF.

Comment: If multiple match is there, it will be fine, if it shows both or one. @user1558604

Comment: Oh I think you have both df of same length....you need column wise comparision or what?

Comment: @AnuragDabas I need it by rowwise for df1, we can also merge the categories for df2, making it more shorter.

Comment: @AnuragDabas I added another picture for df2, like I did a groupby on it, if it can help.